# How to fill a shape with icons automatically?

Tags: vector, icon, fill

I know how to add the icons one by one manually, but is there a way to do it faster/automatically? Is there a generator for this somewhere?

For example (pulled from [here](https://openclipart.org/detail/281073/medical-icons-human-body)):

[image]

Comment: Do you have any specific software you're using or have available to you?

Comment: I'm using Inkscape

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the tag in the question says **vector**, I am going to assume the use of software like Sketch or Illustrator (there may be many more but it's not important)

1. Place all the required icons on the screen. This shouldn't be a difficult task. Just place one group and then copy is all across the screen.
2. Use pen tool or any drawing tool to sketch out the silhouette of the human (or any closed shape you need)
3. Add a fill to this closed shape and bring/keep it as the top-most layer.
4. Select all the items and create a **[clipping mask](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/clipping-masks.html)** or a **[mask](http://www.sketchtips.info/articles/masking)**
5. Done.

This will give you the desired result in very quick time

Answer (score 3):

If you're using illustrator, you might want to take a look at the [ColliderScribe](https://astutegraphics.com/software/colliderscribe/) plugin from AstuteGraphics. It has a feature called [SpaceFIll](https://astutegraphics.com/blog/space-fill-feature-colliderscribe-2/) which takes one or several elements and arranges then within an area, letting you specify parameters like spacing, size, etc.